# ambari + namenode HA and hdfs zkfc -formatZK

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, hdp, namenode

we have production HDP cluster ,

```
HDP version - 2.6.5
Ambari version - 2.6.1
```

We are performing now the change hostname configuration according to the document - https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.0.0/administering-ambari/content/amb_changing_host_names.html

The last stage is talking about – in case `NameNode HA` enabled , then need to run the following command on one of the `name node` machines

```
hdfs zkfc -formatZK -force
```

since we have `active name node` and `standby name node` ,  we assume that our namenode is HA enable!

[image]

but we want to understand  what are the risks when doing the following cli on one of the namenode machines

```
hdfs zkfc -formatZK -force
```

is the below command is safety to run without risks ?